# What am I supposed to do when the hot air balloon runs out of gas?

Tags: mad-max

So I rode a hot air balloon up and down but it "ran out of gas" when I was halfway up. And it wouldn't go up or down or let me out. Is this a bug or am I supposed to do something?

Comment: Shoot some holes in the balloon, maybe?

Comment: No access to weapons

Answer (score 4):

The part about it not going down or letting you out is interesting... It should still descend, although rather slowly (I believe there was a button to speed the descent up a little, I just cannot remember it at the moment, also it might be different for your system, mine was PS4). If it is not going down **at all**, I would recommend trying what I mention below (ensuring the tank is filled completely, which you can see when you try refilling the balloon).

This will actually happen on multiple balloons and appears to just be a simple "puzzle" (if you want to call it that).
If I remember correctly, there will usually be a gas canister a fairly short distance from the balloon site, so you'll just have to do a small amount of exploring to locate it. You could also bring one along in the Magnum Opus and use that to refill the balloon.

I should mention that the balloon does have a small, metal tank on one side that will allow you to refill it, just as you do your car. After that you should be good to go!

Not having enough gas is normal for many of the balloons though, so maybe fully filling it first and ascending all the way up will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a way out of that, shooting balloon, descending, etc. If nothing happens you'll have to load last save when you were out of balloon and before you go in again, fill it up with fuel.
I recommend always having a fuel can in your Magnum Opus.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold R2 to descend, it may look like it's not but it does. If it doesn't work for you then the game is broken and you have to reload.